# Debug Webkitgtk on Linux

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, webkit, webkitgtk

I build a Webkitgtk by `Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --gtk --debug`

Is there a way I can debug it in GDB on linux with an HTML file?

I don't know how to run a WebKitWebProcess that opens an HTML file.

I've found some information in [Debugging WebKitGTK+](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebKitGTK/Debugging), so I tried 
`WEB_PROCESS_CMD_PREFIX='/usr/bin/gdbserver localhost:8080' Tools/Scripts/run-minibrowser --gtk --debug /path/to/my/test.html`

then in another terminal, run `gdb ./WebKitBuild/Debug/bin/WebKitWebProcess` and in GDB, set `target remote localhost:8080`.

However It seems that I cannot find some symbols. For example, `test.html` contains [the vulnerability](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=1593) that crashes at `WebCore::RenderObject::RenderObjectBitfields::isBox()` in an ASAN build of WebKit. However I cannot find it with `info symbol` in gdb with --gtk flag.

I also tried: `gdb ./WebKitBuild/Debug/bin/MiniBrowser` and `run test.html`, but I got

`/nas/ug16zy2/webkit/webkit-2.20.2/WebKitBuild/Debug/bin/MiniBrowser: error while loading shared libraries: libwoff2dec.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I think I might confuse with WebKit and WebKitgtk... Can anyone explain it to me. Thanks a lot.